# How to remove the repeating `place` name which contains the same `name`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I find the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36744732/11328122) help me a lot in removing duplicate object array which contains duplicates.

I've made a [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-duplicates-from-array-of-objects-4txaea?file=index.js) of the example which I modified.

The function related:

```
const uniqueArray = things.thing.filter((thing,index) => {
  return index === things.thing.findIndex(obj => {
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify(thing);
  });
});
```

For example I have:

```
[
  {"place":"here","name":"stuff"},
  {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
  {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
  {"place":"herehere","name":"stuff"}
]
```

It would return:

```
[
  {"place":"here","name":"stuff"},
  {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
  {"place":"herehere","name":"stuff"}
]
```

How to remove the repeating `place` name which contains the same `name`?

Expected output:

```
[
  {"place":"here","name":"stuff"},
  {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"}
]
```

Comment: You may want to use Array.reduce instead, where the accumulator is the "filtered" object, and the next item is pushed only if the accumulator doesn't contain the desired item. `const uniqueArray = things.thing.reduce((acc, next) => {
  if (acc.find(i => i.place === next.place)) return acc;
  else return (acc.push(next), acc);
}, []);
`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array of objects. Simply, if an object with a key value the same as the current object already exists in the accumulator, don't add it again.

Here's a function that allows you specify which key you want to dedupe:

```js
const arr = [
  {"place":"here","name":"stuff"},
  {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
  {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
  {"place":"herehere","name":"stuff"}
];

// Accepts an array and a key that should have the
// duplicates removed
function remove(arr, key) {

  // Iterate over the array passing in the accumulator
  // and the current element
  return arr.reduce((acc, c) => {

    // If there is an object in the accumulator with the
    // same key value as the current element simply return the
    // accumulator
    if (acc.find(obj => obj[key] === c[key])) return acc;

    // Otherwise add the current element to the accumulator
    // and return it
    return acc.concat(c);
  }, []);
}

function showJSON(arr, id) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);
  document.querySelector(`#${id} code`).textContent = json;
}

// remove duplicate places
showJSON(remove(arr, 'place'), 'places');

// remove duplicate names
showJSON(remove(arr, 'name'), 'names');
```

```html
<div id="places">
Removed duplicate places
<pre><code></code></pre>
</div>

<div id="names">
Removed duplicate names
<pre><code></code></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```
  const things = [
        {"place":"here","name":"stuff"},
        {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
        {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
        {"place":"herehere","name":"stuff"}
    ]

    const uniqueArray = things.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        if (accumulator.find(a => a.name === currentValue.name))
            return accumulator;
        else
            return (accumulator.push(currentValue), accumulator);
    }, []);
```

Output

```
    [ { place: 'here', name: 'stuff' },
      { place: 'there', name: 'morestuff' } ]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce check this you can understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use array reduce with filter

```js
let data=[
  {"place":"here","name":"stuff"},
  {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
  {"place":"there","name":"morestuff"},
  {"place":"herehere","name":"stuff"}
]

// Using reduce() to separate the contents we want
let result=data.reduce((acc,value)=>{
  if(acc.filter(val=>val.name==value.name).length==0) // checking the accumulator if it already containsa the value
  {
    acc.push(value); // if the array returned is of length==0 we can push in it
  }
return acc;

},[])
console.log(result);
```

See [Array Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)